# How to hide each item except first one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have 3 divs called .pageSection, I have a jquery each that hides each item, but I do not want to hide the first item, how would I do this? I tried the following, still hads all items, no errors:

```
$('.pageSection').each(function(){
    if($(this).not(":eq(0)")){
         $(this).hide();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No `.each()` needed. Use [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) instead:

```
$('.pageSection:gt(0)').hide();
```